# SwiftUI List from Json Array

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to take this information I've decoded from JSON and put it in a List. I've been using SwiftyJSON to actually get it, but I'm having a hard time actually using it. I've tried several tutorials but no luck, I'm still new to Swift, but JSON is proving to be especially difficult.

To clarify, I have taken the Data from the URL using URLSession

```
guard let data = data else { return }
                    do {
                        //print(data)
                        //outputs 500 bytes
                        let json = try JSON(data: data)
                        //print(json)
                        //out puts the JSON Below
                        
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
```

Here is the JSON

```
{
  "data" : [
    [
      "0",
      "this is a string",
      "this is a string",
      "this is a string",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "this is a string",
      "1"
    ],
    [
      "Int",
      "this is a string",
      "this is a string",
      "this is a string",
      "4",
      "3",
      "7",
      "6",
      "this is a string",
      "5"
    ],
    [
      "0",
      "this is a string",
      "this is a string",
      "this is a string",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "1",
      "this is a string",
      "1"
    ]]}
```

My Goal is to output this date into a view, where each array is a row and each string in the army is a Column.

```
     COLUMN COLUMN COLUMN COLUMN COLUMN COLUMN COLUMN COLUMN COLUMN COLUMN
ROW    0      hi    hi      hi     1      0      0      0      0      0
ROW    0      hi    hi      hi     1      0      0      0      0      0
ROW    0      hi    hi      hi     1      0      0      0      0      0
ROW    0      hi    hi      hi     1      0      0      0      0      0
```

Comment: Can you share your Json Array.

Comment: The code I posted is it, I just replaced the actual values with their types and condensed it to two entries.

Comment: @MatthewPrice - it's kinda odd that you replaced values with the name of their types. Do you mean that you have an object like this: `{ "data": [ [1,"foo"], [2, "bar", 3]] }`, and you want to decode into an array of what? `[[Any]]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Swift 3 (if I'm not mistaken) you have an Json encoder/decoder

Even though your Json seems a bit strange to me it's a valid one and rather easy to replicate, as it contains only one field that contains arrays of arrays of string, if all values are with "" they are treated as strings.

Just create an struct matching your json in this case it would be something like this

```swift
// Struct matching your Json
struct Response: Codable {
    var data: [[String]]
}

// How to read
let jsonData: Data? = yourJsonString.data(using: .utf8)
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
if let callResult = try? decoder.decode(Response.self, from: jsonData!) {
    // your code here
} else {
    // something went wrong
}
```

Now this structure matches exactly your Json file, if your file isn't like that you might need to adjust it.

The variables in the struct must match the json field, for instance in your json you have the field "data" then your structure must contain the variable "data" you can change the name of the variables but you need to explicitly tell swift for instance

```swift
struct Response: Codable {
    var otherVariableName: [[String]]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case otherVariableName = "data"
    }
}
```

Take a look into this [tutorial](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/json-parsing-decoding/)